# can't read csv file on hdfs - Hadoop

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to read a csv file but i get : `No such file or directory.`

the file is on tmp folder.

This is the commands:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Your file is **not at** `hdfs:///user/hdfs/titles.csv`, and this is what the error is saying.

You are only showing `ls`, not `hdfs dfs -ls`, so you should be using just `cat titles.csv`

If you want to read a file from HDFS, you need to `hdfs dfs -put titles.csv /user/hdfs/` first. (And create the user directory using `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/hdfs` if it doesn't already exist)

Comment: Even `hdfs dfs -cat titles`.csv` show no such file or directory

Comment: Yes, that was the error in your original question... Like I said, you need to make the `/user/hdfs` folder on HDFS, then `-put` the file before you can cat it. After that, you should write the full command as `hdfs dfs -cat /user/$(whoami)/titles.csv` until you get it working, then you can remove the path prefix

Comment: i did it as you told me, but i get always the same error

Comment: What error do you get with `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/$(whoami)`?