# difference between -ls and hdfs dfs -ls

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

i want to know what's the difference between :

`hdfs@hdfs-namenode-0:/ $ ls` and `hdfs@hdfs-namenode-0:/ $ hdfs dfs -ls /`

[image]

Meanwhile i want to read a csv file which is on tmp but i get always no such file or directory :

[image]

So this work is all in kubernetes(minikube).

Thanks for help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't read csv file on hdfs - Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545511/cant-read-csv-file-on-hdfs-hadoop)

Comment: Did you run `hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hdfs` or not? Please show `hdfs dfs -ls /user`

Comment: @OneCricketeer i found 2 items : user/hdfs , user/root

Comment: Then you should be able to create a local file. `echo 'example' > file.txt` Then upload it `hdfs dfs -put file.txt`, see it `hdfs dfs -ls`, then cat it `hdfs dfs -cat file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` is like `dir` in windows. It shows you the content of a specific folder.
hdfs is Hadoop Distributed File System. In your example the output is like a `ls -l`

For your 2nd question:
Your file isn't in your hdfs.
If you do this:

```bash
hdfs dfs -ls
```

There shouldn't be a titles.csv file. In fact, you have done this in your first picture. There are no files at all (except maybe there are invisible files).

If you do this:

```bash
hdfs dfs -ls titles.csv
```

The output would be: "No such file or directory"
You should use just:

```bash
cat -n /tmp/titles.csv
```

For Further informationen:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls